# Оживление кнопок меню при использовании библиотеки Swing в Java

Tags: java, swing

Работая в среде NetBeans я наткнулся на проблему. Я создал панель меню и мне нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки в меню открывалось новое окошко с текстом. Очень прошу кого-нибудь написать фрагмент кода для такой операции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код для открытия мессаджбокса:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Message text");
```

Код для привязки действия к кнопке:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Код действия кнопки, например,
        //код открытия мессаджбокса
    }
});
```